# Not working in FireFox: div width to fill line and jump to new line when not enough space

Tags: html, css, firefox, width

I have two divs:

- one is floated right (this one has constant size)
- the other has width auto and overflow hidden, it uses all the leftover space   in the line and when less space is available than the min-width, it jumps to the lower line, filling it

This is the behaviour I want, but it **isn't working in FireFox**, where it just stops adjusting its width and **starts moving over the constant size div**.

*fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/qxda20g9/*

```
<style>
.noadjust {
width:330px;
height:40px;
float:right;
background-color:teal;
color:white;
}
.automagic {
min-width: 160px;
overflow: hidden;
width: auto;
padding: 5px;
min-height: 30px;
background-color:lightblue;
}
</style>

<div class="noadjust">constant size</div>
<div class="automagic">fills line or drops to next</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but if the container div has a border-top or padding-top it resolves the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/nhprvk72/

```
<div id="contain" style="padding-top:1px;">
```

Will love to know the why of it if anyone cares to explain.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
@media (max-width: 161px) {
    .automagic { display: block; width: 100%; clear: both; }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lecv8oor/

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer doing it without media queries.